# In app product rejected state getting invalid product id

Tags: ios, xcode, in-app-purchase

We have submitted our app for review with few in app purchase. Apple rejected our app due to some other reason and the in-app product also got rejected.

Now the issue is i cant able to test in-app purchase in sandbox mode, It always returns as invalid product id. Before the app rejection i have tested it many times in sandbox mode without any issue. Even i tried to create test product, but it still shows in invalid product id. How can i solve this issue ? How can i test in-app purchase now?

Even if i upload again new build how they will test if the in-app purchase not working means? I have tried with many links nothing gives me clear idea!! Thanks in advance.

Comment: what is the exact reason apple has given for rejection?

Comment: @SatishMavani That is for ipv6 issue

Comment: Have you try by creating new product?

Comment: Yep, tried creating new product, but I am still getting invalid product id.